# Persisting a list of an interface type with JPA2

Tags: jpa

I suspect there's no perfect solution to this problem so least worst solution are more than welcome.

I'm implementing a dashboard using PrimeFaces and I would like to persist the model backing it (using JPA2). I've written my own implementation of DashboardModel and DashboardColumn with the necessary annotations and other fields I need. The model is shown below:

```
@Entity
public class DashboardSettings implements DashboardModel, Serializable{

    @Id
    private long id;
    @OrderColumn( name="COLUMN_ORDER" )
    private List<DashboardColumn> columns;

    ...a few other fields...

    public DashboardSettings() {}

    @Override
    public void addColumn(DashboardColumn column) {
        this.columns.add(column);
    }

    @Override
    public List<DashboardColumn> getColumns() {
        return columns;
    }

    ...snip...
}
```

The problem is the columns field. I would like this field to be persisted into it's own table but because DashboardColumn is an interface (and from a third party so can't be changed) the field currently gets stored in a blob. If I change the type of the columns field to my own implementation (DashboardColumnSettings) which is marked with @Entity the addColumn method would cease to work correctly - it would have to do a type check and cast.

The type check and cast is not the end of the world as this code will only be consumed by our development team but it is a trip hazard. Is there any way to have the columns field persisted while at the same time leaving it as a DashboardColumn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `targetEntity` attribute, though I'm note sure it would be better than explicit cast:

```
@OrderColumn( name="COLUMN_ORDER" )
@OneToMany(targetEntity = DashboardColumnSettings.class)
private List<DashboardColumn> columns;
```

Comment: Nice simple solution to the problem, cheers. I ended up having to provide a method that performed the cast anyway but this is a good trick to know.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the JPA implementation (you don't mention which one); the JPA spec doesn't define support for interface fields, nor for Collections of interfaces. DataNucleus JPA certainly allows it, primarily because we support it for JDO also, being something that is part of the JDO spec.